# Can I use search or regex to catch debugger output with a breakpoint in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm getting this super obnoxious output printed out thousands of times slowing down my program:

```
2021-11-08 12:37:57.183588-0800 (myScheme)[27459:701276] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(144) Failed to log metrics
```

In StackOverflow, I'm only finding that it is related to an XCode bug and there isn't much that can be done about it.  However, I'd like to experiment with alternative pieces of code that might be able to perform whatever task is being run but without triggering this stupid issue.

Is there a way I can set a breakpoint for this so I can study the stack trace which leads to it?

Thanks

Comment: No, your code is not emitting it. It just means you're networking.

Comment: My code might not be directly emitting it but I don’t see this when I run a new project so it must be triggering it some how.

Comment: Triggering at some remove, sure. But the point is there is nothing for you to breakpoint. Do you see?

Comment: Break points would be one means to the end of figuring out where the heck this code base is triggering the issue.  When I disable all logging I notice an improvement in performance.  I suspect this is being output thousands of times judging on my debugger line count.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

1. This output is a simple logging statement (such as generated by `OSLog` or `Logger`) in a framework. You generally cannot control what logging these frameworks do, so don’t worry about it.
2. In terms of slowing down your app, the logging system is exceptionally efficient, depending upon the level of the individual logging message, so I wager that debugging messages are not slowing down your app (observably). There are different logging levels, i.e., “debug”, “info”, “notice”, “error”, and “fault”, each with its own performance characteristics. See WWDC 2020 [Exploring logging in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger/). In particular, “debug” logging messages are highly performant.
3. The real issue is how to filter your debugger console so your salient logging statements don’t get lost in all the cruft from logging statements from all the frameworks you might be using (such as “boringssl”).

   I find that filtering the console is extremely useful. Unfortunately, The Xcode console filter does not offer regex or “negative” filters (i.e., you cannot say “show me everything except `boringssl` messages”). But you can tell it to show you your particular logging statements.

   In particular, you might consider using `Logger` (or `OSLog` for older targets), instead of `print`, for your logging statements:

   ```swift
   import os

   private let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "AppDelegate") // use whatever category you want; I personally use a separate logger for each compilation unit and make the “category” the name of that unit
   ```

   And later, in lieu of `print`, use `Logger`:

   ```swift
   logger.debug(...)
   ```

   (In older targets, you can use `OSLog`; the syntax is slightly different, but the idea is the same.)

   Anyway, when I then look at my unfiltered log, I’ll see all the cruft, where it is hard to see the messages I care about:

   [image]

   But I can focus on my salient events, in this case by filtering on “[AppDele” for log messages from my `AppDelegate`:

   [image]

   This logging pattern also allows you to watch iOS logging messages emitted by a device on one’s macOS Console, which is critical when diagnosing issues that only manifest themselves when not attached to a debugger. This is illustrated in that [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logger/).

In short, do not worry about framework logging messages, but just have a workflow that lets you easily focus on the console messages that matter.

Comment: This is a great approach, and I use it too. One thing to remember: if you don't stop filtering, Xcode won't stop filtering. I wish I had a nickel for every lldb command I've gotten "no response" to, only to realize I've filtered it out.